Is it possible to split columns or repeat horizontally in a Grafana table visualisation?
I have a table monitoring the online status of a group of devices. Currently it's 36 but will increase in the future. At the moment the table is one long column that I have to scroll through, or I enable pagination and go through that way.
Ideally I'd like the column to show 10-15 results and then repeat horizontally until all devices are displayed on one screen so I can easily see if a device is down.
Table of devices
What I'd like
I've searched all transform options and table options but I can't find how to do this.

I don't think this is possible for Table panel (at least for vanilla one). But I believe if you switch to panel Stat, it would produce something similar.

What is your datasource? May be you can adjust your query so as to get a desired layout?
